# Send C#/razor to javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

How I can make it work:

```
@foreach (var alert in Model.AlertsRelatedToBrand)
 {
     <li class="notifications-row">
         <div class="notifications-icon notifications-icon-alert">&nbsp</div>
         <div class="notifications-text"><a>@alert.Title</a></div>
         <a href="#" class="notifications-dismiss" onclick="onHideAlertClick(@alert.Id)">x</a> // here is problem
     </li>
}
```

I want to send id of each alert to function if item was clicked.

Comment: Error message would be very helpful..

Comment: is the id an int or a string?

Comment: Try messing around with the quotes... onclick="onHideAlertClick('@alert.Id')" or onclick='onHideAlertClick(@alert.Id)' etc etc

Comment: What does your `onHideAlertClick()` function look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears correct as the use of `@alert.Id` should output the value into your existing `onHideAlertClick()` function :

```
onclick="onHideAlertClick(@alert.Id)"
```

It's worth noting that if your `Id` property is an integer, you may want to try wrapping the parameter within single quotes to pass it along as a string as seen below :

```
onclick="onHideAlertClick('@alert.Id')"
```